# Can't connect a go app to mysql (both inside a gitlab runner)

Tags: mysql, go, gitlab-ci-runner

The go app simply inserts a harcoded value in a mysql table and spits it back out. This is done using [this database driver](http://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql). It works fine on linux servers, but during gitlab's CI this returns:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
```

This is the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: mysql
services:
  - mysql:latest
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: storage
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_HOST: mysql
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_TRANSAPORT: tcp
  MYSQL_ADDRESS: "127.0.0.1:3306"
job:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qq curl && apt-get install -qq git
    - echo "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';" | mysql --user="$MYSQL_USER" --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host="$MYSQL_HOST" "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
    - curl -O https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    - tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    - rm go1.10.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    - echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
    - echo "export GOPATH=\$HOME/go" >> ~/.bashrc
    - echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$GOPATH/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
    - source ~/.bashrc
    - go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
    - go build main.go
    - ./main
```

Is there a standard way to use mysql from golang during CI?

Comment: Did you [read this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html)?

Comment: I expect the root of your problem is that you're setting `MYSQL_ADDRESS`, and you shouldn't be.

Comment: Also, you misspelled `MYSQL_TRANSPORT`

Comment: Yeah I've read that one.

Comment: The mysql command proves that the installation works fine, since it outputs the correct port: 3306. And the environment variables, besides the password and databse variables, serve only to configure the go app.

Comment: That proves that the mysql _client_ is installed correctly. It also proves that there's no server running on that host/port.

Comment: I suggest following the directions in that document precisely, rather than adding your own config variables.